# How to make a Loop for nth position 1, 11,21,31,41,51,61..... to paginate with add scroll listener

Tags: java, android, loops

Hello Developers and Teachers , i am encountering a problem while looping on nth position in a String Url. Everything is working fine for me but in the following code the recyclerview listener is calling 10 times the same item alternatively and then moving to the next position. I mean to say for example (Item1, item2, Item3...Item10 ) is calling 10 times i.e after Item10 the recyclerview listener is calling again (Item1, item2, Item3...Item10 ) for 10 times and after 10 times then the new items are added as (Item11, item12, Item13...Item20 ) and repeatedly so on.

I think i am making the loop wrong in the String Url. For me i need the numberPosition in the  String url = "http://www.example.com/posts?item_position="+numberPosition";  should be changing in the position (1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71 .....) while calling the infinite Scroll in recyclerview using add on listener. Please help me to solve this issue. I shall be very thankful.

```
 int count = 0;
@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

    int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
    int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
    int firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

    if (!isLoading() && !isLastPage()) {
        if ((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount
                && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0) {
            count++;
            loadMoreItems();

        }
    }
}



    public void loadMoreItems() {
int numberPosition;

      if (numberPosition < 0) {
         numberPosition=1
      } else {
         numberPosition = 1+(count-1) * 10;
      }
     String url = "http://www.example.com/posts?item_position="+numberPosition";
    }
```

Comment: try using EndlessScrollListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListenercheck https://guides.codepath.com/android/endless-scrolling-with-adapterviews-and-recyclerviewfor more detail

Comment: Thank you Sir for letting me know, i will try to implement it.And also Sir if you have a solution in the above code, please do help me.Thanking You.@Android User

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of variable scope concept?
In your second method variable numberPosition is re-declared twice which should not be the case. Either numberPosition should be class variable or you should pass the numberPosition in loadMoreItems() method. You cannot keep redeclaring it, it will definitely give wrong output.

Addition to answer:
As far as I could guess, modify your code as follows.

```
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
int firstVisibleItemPosition =      layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
int numberPosition;
if (!isLoading() && !isLastPage()) {
    if ((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount
            && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0) {
        count++;
        numberPosition = visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition;
        loadMoreItems(numberPostion);

    }
}
```

}

```
public void loadMoreItems(int numberPosition) {


  if (numberPosition < 0) {
     numberPosition=1
  } else {
     numberPosition = 1+(count-1) * 10;
  }
 String url = "http://www.example.com/posts?item_position="+numberPosition";
}
```

Comment: What I could understand from your code is that method loadMoreItems() should add more items after sum of (visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition). But this sum should be sent to loadMoreItems Method, which then uses it as number position. In any case numberpostion should not be redeclared in loadMoreItems. So do not use 'int numberPosition = 1' rather 'numberPosition = 1'

Comment: Sir thanks for replying, Sir i shall be very thankful if you give me the solution in the answer box. Sir please dont mind for not knowing about the variable concept. Sir i am not from a computer background and so i use to face lot of difficulties and challenges. Whatever i am learning of my own and it has been I year since. And thankyou sir to find be the issue, today itself i will study about the concept of variable scope. Thanking you once again. @ShazHere

Comment: Sir i understood the bug in the question and so i modified the question but sir still i am having the same issue.@ShazHere

Comment: I added more description and tried to guess your solution. Does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

looking at your code, I can only GUESS(really just guess) what you are trying to do is something like this. Maybe you can copy and try the code below... Thanks.

```
public void loadMoreItems() {
    int numberPosition;

    if (count <= 0) {
        count = 1;
    }

    numberPosition = 1 + (count - 1) * 10;

    String url = "http://www.example.com/posts?item_position=" + numberPosition;
}
```

Comment: No Sir it is not Working and also it will not,Sir please help me to find another solution@QingyuZhao

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice you against using OnScrolled. It is an not efficient method. Use [Paged Lists](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedList) for better results.

Solution:

- You need to add another variable => private boolean isLoading =
  false;
- When you reach the end of the recyclerView && isLoading ==
  false, only then call => loadMoreItems().
- First thing to do inside loadMoreItems() is => isLoading = true; so that the method wont be called multiple times like in your case. Once loadMoreItems() has
  completed its task, you can => isLoading = false; so that the next
  time you reach bottom of the recy

clerView, the method could be called.

But, I suggest you use Paged Lists, its got beautiful examples.

Comment: Sir thanks for replying ,and yes sir you are absolutely correct and i have already added that in the code as  isLoading == false. Sir the above code was just an example . I think i am having the problem only in making tthe loop for the String Url to change the position as numberPosition. And Sir i will let you know while adding the clearview method.@Ravi Kiran Svs